# Storing all data of a website on Apache Jena as RDF?

Tags: java, php, rdf, jena, semantic-web

I am trying to build a web site build on semantic technologies. It is a CMS, to make it simple lets say it's a blog. I need to be able to do simple CRUD operations. All data will be saved on Jena like blog posts, user informations, blog categories etc.

I have a php system. Here is the path what i am planing to follow:

1. Use Apache Jena as RDF Store
2. Use Apache Jena for storing and retrieving the data.
3. Write a web service on java
4. Communicate through web service with PHP in JSON format to view, control the data.

My main focus is to build a web site on semantic technologies. 
Is there anything wrong with my approach?

If not the main question is when a user made a blog post how will i create a relation with the blog post and user.
With mysql it was just a froeign key. How can i make a relations on Jena between new blog post and existing user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see anything wrong with your approach. Maybe I would suggest to use JSON-LD as an interchange format, because Jena can read it and write it directly instead of having to create your own converters to RDF (see https://jena.apache.org/documentation/io/).

Regarding the modeling question, I strongly recommend to have a look at the SIOC vocabulary (http://rdfs.org/sioc/spec/), which aims to represent exactly what you are looking for, and more.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. The SIOC vocabulary fits perfectly for my application i will use it. I still don't understand that how can i make relations wtih the new blog post and existing user. I would normally send the user id from session information but can't figure out this one. Maybe i need some graph db knowledge?

Comment: You will need to have a look at the RDF basics: https://code.google.com/p/tdwg-rdf/wiki/Beginners3RDFbasics. Then, you will need to use URIs to identify blogs, users and model the relationship among them with the SIOC vocabulary

Answer (score 0):

Another hardcore solution would be to create the pages of the website in RDF (serialized in RDF/XML), and use XSL to generate the HTML version on demand for each page. It really depends on the size of your website.